# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/discovery/tools/DiscoverSingleton

Tags: java, web-services

here i am trying to make call using webservices via wsdl, while running code getting following exception.
showing the testing code as well, please help me out. Thanks.

```
 import org.apache.axis.client.Service;
import org.apache.axis.client.Call;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import java.net.URL;


public class WebTest {
    Service service = null;

    String endpoint = "http://mytest.com/test/Signup.jws";
    String userName =  "globel";
    String userPw =  new String(Base64.decodeBase64("Z23fG46732345FG=".getBytes()));;

    public WebTest() {
        try {
            service = new Service();
            System.out.println("*** executed successfully ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception - " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public void testWeb(String f1, String f2, String f3, int itemcode, String f4){
    try {
            Call call = (Call)service.createCall();
            call.setTargetEndpointAddress(new URL(endpoint));
            call.setOperationName(new QName("emp"));
            call.setUsername(userName);
            call.setPassword(userPw);
            Object[] params = new Object[5];
            params[0] = new String(f1);
            params[1] = new String(f2);
            params[2] = new String(f3);
            params[3] = new Integer(itemcode);
            params[4] = new String(f4); 
            call.invoke(params);

        } catch (Exception e) {
             System.out.println("Exception - " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String orderDate = "03-Jan-2013";
        WebTest webtest= new WebTest() ;
        webtest.testWeb("rayban","aviator",orderDate,82724,"113000") ;
    }

}
```

> getting following error -
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/commons/discovery/tools/DiscoverSingleton  at
>   org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory$1.run(LogFactory.java:45)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory.getLogFactory(LogFactory.java:41)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory.(LogFactory.java:33)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.handlers.BasicHandler.(BasicHandler.java:43)
>     at org.apache.axis.client.Service.getAxisClient(Service.java:207)   at
>   org.apache.axis.client.Service.(Service.java:225)

Comment: Seems that your application server is missing the `org/apache/commons/discovery/tools/*` folder. Have you linked it explicitely to your project via BuildPath?

Comment: yes, added commons-discovery-0.4 jar and problem resolved.

Comment: Maybe you also need to add the library to the DeploymentAssembly of your project, so that it is getting copied to the application servers directory.

Comment: didn't get your point.

Comment: Via 'Project'->'Properties'->'DeploymentAssembly' you can specify which of the referenced libraries via the projects BuildPath (that are not part of the application server distribution or arn't explicitely added to the application servers lib folder) should be automatically deployed on the applicationserver at project startup.

Answer (score 9):

For maven users: add commons-discovery dependency to your pom.xml file
e.g

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
    <version>0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Added discovery-0.4.jar to my code and it resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

in my case I added commons-discovery-0.2.jar

Answer (score 0):

Add pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
        <version>0.5</version>
    </dependency>
```